# What is the value/cost of enabling "spread spectrum clocking" on my hard drives?

Tags: storage, hard-drive, sata

I'm building up a biggish NAS box (10x [WD RE4](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.asp?driveid=732) 2TB SATA RAID10) and ran into some problems.  During the course of my research, debugging, investigations, etc, I discovered a jumper on the physical drives labeled *"[spread spectrum clocking](http://www.google.ch/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=spread+spectrum+clocking)"*.

<strike>After some googling about this on *teh internets*, it seems to be a feature that some suggest (without reference or explanation) enabling in *'a storage configuration'* that makes the drive less sussesptable to [EMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference).</strike>

But why?  I've got three core questions:

1. Why is this feature not enabled by default?
2. What are the actual benefits?
3. Are there any costs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spread Spectrum setting is used to reduce the measurable amount of EMI a device may cause. In a computer, all devices (CPU, RAM, PCI bus, SATA, IDE, etc) operate at a multiple/fraction of the system clock. With all activities happening at exactly the same time, electromagnetic radiation is emitted at a very narrow frequency. Since the energy is concentrated in such a narrow frequency range, it is measured as being more powerful than if it were spread over a wider frequency range.

Spreading EMI over a wide frequency range allows device manufacturers to certify their devices at lower EMI levels. This is because the FCC (USA), JEITA (Japan), and IEC (Europe) measure EMI [within narrow frequency bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum#Spread-spectrum_clock_signal_generation). The wide frequency at which a device causes EMI, the lower the levels of measured EMI.

1. I'm surprised it's disabled by default from a regulatory perspective, according to my research it would be enabled by default. It probably depends on the manufacturer and the country of origin. A technical reason for disabling the feature is below (number 3).
2. The benefit is that it allows a manufacturer to certify a device as causing lower levels of EMI.
3. The feature has the drawback of [reducing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum#Spread-spectrum_clock_signal_generation) the maximum clock speed of a device, causing [compatibility issues](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_Spectrum_Clocking) with some RAID controllers, and [reducing the bandwidth](http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=214011&NewLang=en) of SATA drives from 3Gbps to 1.5Gbps

I'd stay away from Spread Spectrum Clocking.

Disclaimer: I'm not a physicist, I just read a few Wiki pages.

Comment: Errr, 3Gbps to 1.5Gbps, not 1.5Bps, right?

Answer (score 2):

"Spread spectrum clocking" (SSC) lets a SATA-III (default 6 Gb/s) HDD be
recognized by a SATA-I (1.5 Gb/s-only) computer. The drive manufacturer
has to provide this capability to claim SATA compliance, but computer and
OS vendors don't want people to know it's there, so the manufacturer uses
obfuscating terminology and doesn't document SSC's real purpose anywhere.